# Azure Sql table Column Collation Doesn't work for Turkish

Tags: azure, collation, azure-sql-database

I changed the collation of my column using script below as msdn suggests

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ALTER COLUMN NameTR 
            varchar(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CS_AS
```

when I check with the query

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()   
WHERE name LIKE 'SQL%' and description like '%turkish%';
```

It returns me only 2 options as shown below. So either of them should be working for me.

[image]

However when I insert data into that column, I can see the `ğ` is converted into `g`,
`ı` is converted into `i` and so on... only letter is working surprisingly is `ç`

when I verify my column, with the query, it looks fine to me. So why I can insert data correctly into this azure table?

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.columns      WHERE     name = 'nametr'
```

[image]

When I copy paste the value into the column using VS 2015 sql server explorer, It works fine but why It doesnt work using insert query. Do I have to collate insert query somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer finally. Insert statement should have N-prefix as below which is actually described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-collations-in-sql-azure/) under title static strings. I hope this helps someone else having same issue

```
INSERT INTO table      VALUES(N'え', N'え'), ('え', 'え')
```